# iPhone -- black screen in simulator -- viewcontroller

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator

I have searched this forum and looked at various solutions to the "black screen" view issue when a screen is loaded on the iPhone simulator, but I believe my problem is unique and thus I have not yet been able to find a solution.

Here is what is happening:

- ViewB loads correctly when I link ViewA to ViewB using Interface Builder using "push" segue (drag line over, select "push");
- the "push" is executed when a button on ViewA is pressed.

However, when I try to load ViewB programmatically when the button on ViewA is pressed, ViewB appears as a black screen. Here is what I am doing:

- I am using the latest version of XCode;
- `-(void) loadView` has been commented out of ViewB;
- I created ViewA and ViewB using Interface Builder *and* there is no .xib file for either View, so I believe I cannot use the "initWithNibName" parameter (?) when programmatically alloc + init'ing ViewB (?) when the button is pressed.
- I have a NavigationController, ViewA is the "RootView," and a ViewController for each of ViewA and ViewB.
- The code I am using to programmatically load ViewB from the ViewA button press is as follows:

  ViewB *viewB = [[ViewB alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewB animated:YES];

Does anyone have any solutions?  (P.S--this community is amazing!!!)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the ViewController with initWithNibName:@"" bundle:
Put the name of the XIB file for that view in the place of first argument without the extension ".xib" and set the bundle to nil or [NSBundle mainBundle]. You can further check on the Apple Documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  What if I did not create a .xib when I created the class associated with ViewB?

Comment: I may have to use "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier set in identity inspector for ViewController".  I will try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using storyboards you should initialize your ViewController like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
ViewControllerB *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
[self.navigationController viewController animated:YES];
```

In interface Builder you should set the identifier of the view controller you're try to initialize to "identifier"

(MianStoryboard_iPhone is of course your storyboard's name!)

Answer (score 0):

probably [self navigationController] is nil, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your XIB is messed up. You can try to delete the viewcontroller.m[h][xib] and add a new one. Before do that, copy and past the content of the m and h file. After add the new empty viewcontroller, just past the contents. Unfortunately you'll have to assemble the xib again.